# Retrieve a list with short commit messages for each file

Tags: bash, git, shell

I try to retrieve a list of every file in my repository with the commit short message (of the commit when it was changed last time), the date and author name. It should look like on github:

[image: Snap of githublist]

I already tried

```
for file in */*; do    
    echo $f $(git log --pretty=format:"%an %s" -- $f)
done
```

The elapse time for my repository is around 20 seconds. That is way to slow. This repository just contains around 500 files. It has to work for repos with 16k files as well.
Therefore, I just tried:

```
git log --pretty=format:"%an %s" -- */*
```

This prints every commit in the repo with an elapse time around 0.5 seconds. The performance  is good, but I could not find a way to print the changed files in the commit.

I already read about the formats and could not find something usefull.

Ideas?

I'm using git 2.14 on my system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the raw flag will also show the files associated with each commit. You can then pipe the output through to awk to just list the filenames as opposed to the filenames as well as file mode etc

```
git log --raw --pretty=format:"%an %s" | awk '!/^:/ {print $0 } /^:/ { print $6 }'
```

To get the commit message associated with each file, use:

```
git log --raw --pretty=format:"%an %s %f" | awk '!/^:/ {mess=$0 } /^:/ { fils[$6]=mess } END { for ( i in fils ) { print i" - "fils[i]} }'
```

Here, we use awk to put the commit messages into an array indexed by the filenames.

Comment: Great, that almost what I needed.
Do I have to find the last commit message for a file by myself?

Comment: Did you mean `--name-only` instead of `--raw` plus `awk`? ;)

Comment: @Mike I've added a second section to the answer to show the last commit associated with each file.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works well. I just need to take look at awk.
@j6t    --name-only works as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try with `--compact-summary` option:

```
git log --compact-summary
```

From [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

> **--compact-summary**
> Output a condensed summary of extended header information such as file creations or deletions ("new" or "gone", optionally "+l" if it’s a symlink) and mode changes ("+x" or "-x" for adding or removing executable bit respectively) in diffstat. The information is put between the filename part and the graph part. Implies --stat.

Comment: --compact-summary was introduced with version 2.17. I cannot use it.
And the link of documentation points to a local file on C: